# Extract Html content using silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to extract the html content using silverlight. My application aim is to enable user to navigate to any html page and when he clicks a button that page content should be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab any HTML content from any site using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();    
string html = client.DownloadString("http://www.msn.com");
```

Comment: Using system.net.Webclient doesnot contain a definition for download string. Are you missing an assembly reference.?. Which assembly reference i have to use.Below are the reference i have used.
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

Answer (score 0):

Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). it seems be useful for your issue.

See [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/225113/) for using it on Silverlight:

> Have you tried using the HAPLight project that is in the SVN repository right now. It is a Silverlight version of Html Agility Pack and should work on WP7 with little modification (it targets Silverlight 4 so you may need to remove a few things)

Comment: Can you provide somelink so that i'll learn how to htmlagility in silverlight. I'm new to this silverlight so please help me solving my problem

Comment: [Simple code sample is here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples). because of you are using .Net and C# this Lib can be useful.

Comment: When i'm trying to add htmlagility reference its giving error as:
You can't add a reference to HtmlAgilityPack.dll as it was not built against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight projects will only work with Silverlight assemblies.